# How to union 2 data frames with conditions PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I have two data frames with the same three columns: id, date1, date2

I want to union them together but filter out all records that have the same id and date1 but different value for date2.
 For example:

```
id   date1        date2
1    01/01/2010   01/02/2010
2    02/02/2010   02/03/2010
3    03/03/2010   03/04/2010

id   date1        date2
2    02/02/2010   02/04/2010
2    02/02/2010   02/03/2010
4    04/04/2010   04/05/2010
```

For the above 2 data frames, the result should be:

```
id   date1        date2 
1    01/01/2010   01/02/2010
2    02/02/2010   02/03/2010
3    03/03/2010   03/04/2010
2    02/02/2010   02/03/2010
4    04/04/2010   04/05/2010
```

Please do not use SQL statements

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1.show() #sample1

#+---+----------+----------+
#| id|     date1|     date2|
#+---+----------+----------+
#|  1|01/01/2010|01/02/2010|
#|  2|02/02/2010|02/03/2010|
#|  3|03/03/2010|03/04/2010|
#+---+----------+----------+

df2.show() #sample2

#+---+----------+----------+
#| id|     date1|     date2|
#+---+----------+----------+
#|  2|02/02/2010|02/04/2010|
#|  2|02/02/2010|02/03/2010|
#|  4|04/04/2010|04/05/2010|
#+---+----------+----------+
```

Using **`outer-join`** on **`id and date1`** :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window


df1.join(df2.withColumnRenamed("date2","date_2"), ['id','date1'], 'outer')\
   .withColumn("date2", F.expr("""IF(date2 is null, date_2,date2)""")).drop("date_2").show()

#+---+----------+----------+
#| id|     date1|     date2|
#+---+----------+----------+
#|  1|01/01/2010|01/02/2010|
#|  4|04/04/2010|04/05/2010|
#|  2|02/02/2010|02/03/2010|
#|  2|02/02/2010|02/03/2010|
#|  3|03/03/2010|03/04/2010|
#+---+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It helps a lot!